# How to override Sklearn's TSNE to be used in a Pipeline function?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, overriding, pipeline

I am trying to make a custom function for TSNE so it can be used in a Sklearn make_pipeline function.

Generally, for PCA, I would do the following:

```
make_pipeline(PCA(),
              LinearRegression())
```

However, when I tried this:

```
make_pipeline(TSNE(),
              LinearRegression())
```

I would get an error, saying that it does not have a transform() method, and it couldn't use the fit_transform() method. So, now I'm trying to create a custom transform() method using this:

```
class TSNE_wrapper(TSNE):
  def transform(X):
    return TSNE().fit_transform(X)
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
transform() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: I added another method called fit(), looks like it's working now. My bad

Comment: I added "self" to each of the methods describe by @Mike so I ended up with: ```class TSNE_wrapper(TSNE):
    def transform(self, X):
        return TSNE().fit_transform(X)
    def fit(self):
        return TSNE().fit()```

Answer (score 4):

you're right about the fix however you should not do it!

### PCA

PCA creates embedding by finding the axis that maximizes the variance: 
given the training set you find directions (linear combination of the axes (x,y,z etc...)) where the data varies a lot. The result of a fitted PCA are the k directions (k linear combination of the axis) (it's the .components attribute in sklearn). You can then transform your test data by applying the linear combination to the test points.

### TSNE

TSNE in the other hand creates low dimension embedding that tries to respect (at a certain level) the distance between the points in the real dimensions. TSNE doesn't look at points given their position in the high dimension space it just looks at the distance between that point and its neighbors. And try to respect these relations in the low dims space.
This is why Sklearn doesn't have a transform function for that class, you cannot transform data using TSNE: TSNE transform function needs to fit the data first.

- Check that very good article if you want more info : http://mlexplained.com/2018/09/14/paper-dissected-visualizing-data-using-t-sne-explained/

### Back to your question

If you use your pipeline with a training / test split the TSNE object will be retrained at test time using the test data ! And there are NO reasons that the embedding would look the same as the one fitted with the training data (again since the embedding depends on the points given during the training). The performance of your ML model should be bad !

If you really want to use TSNE and then machine learning you have to fit transform the whole dataset train and test: but remember that your machine learning function would be useless since you leaked test data !

Comment: This link doesn't seem right. IT takes me to an random page.